# After confirmation, navigate to first tab of wizard

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Pretty much, everything is said in title of topic.What I need to achieve is that when I am in last (confirm) tab of wizard and click on my button, after everything is done, I want to back to first tab of wizard. Of course, everything in wizard should be reset after that.

---

Well, it isn't help. Currently I am totally confused. On click of button I get this exception, but not in server log, only in browser I get:

An Error Occurred:

java.lang.NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataHelper.decodeFilters(DataHelper.java:167)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:51)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:980)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.processDecodes(DataTable.java:542)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1042)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processDecodes(Panel.java:282)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1042)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1042)
at org.primefaces.component.wizard.Wizard.processDecodes(Wizard.java:210)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:216)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1042)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1042)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:941)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Button looks like this:

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Save service" action="#{kuBean.saveService}"
                                         update="growl"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...

Assuming that your bean is `@ViewScoped` then a simple page redirect to the url of your wizard page should reinstantiate your wizards managed bean.  If that doesn't work you can append the GET property `[url]?faces-redirect=true` to the URL.

This won't work if your managed bean is `@SessionScoped` however as the data and state information from the previous wizard confirmation will likely still be there.  The best solution would be to switch to ViewScoped and if that is not possible then write a reset method of the managed bean that can clear the state and data of the managed bean.

Answer (score 0):

try using the *flowListener* of the *p:wizard*

```
<p:wizard flowListener="#{userWizard.handleFlow}">
...
</p:wizard>
```

in your bean:

```
public String handleFlow(FlowEvent event) {
   String currentStepId = event.getCurrentStep();
   String stepToGo = event.getNextStep();
   //if(skip)
   //return "confirm";
   //else
   //return event.getNextStep();

   ... portion where you are to return to the first tab
   return "id_value_of_first_tab";
}
```